# How to integrate API Gateway with S3 AWS Service using greedy path proxy resource

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have files in an S3 bucket that I am serving using AWS API Gateway

I have a resource `GET /{file}` that maps to `mybucket:/{file}`

ie `http://myapigateway.com/test1.txt` correctly returns `mybucket:/test1.txt`

Now I want to serve files with directory paths:

`http://myapigateway.com/dirA/test2.txt` should return the file `mybucket:/dirA/test2.txt`

I can not get this to work. The problem is that when I set the new API Gateway resource to use greedy path matches as a "proxy resource":

`GET /{proxy+}`

I no longer have the option to integrate with s3 (see image below)

I tried to pass the `method.request.querystring.proxy` var instead of `method.request.path.proxy` to prevent the slashes from being stripped but that didn't help.

If I can't integrate with s3 directly, is there any way I can work-around with a lambda function?

[screen-shot: no option to integrate with AWS Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuZrz.png)